# Adding styling to rails react component wrapping div

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs, react-rails

I'm using `react_component` in my Rails project. This inserts a wrapping div for the `react.js` component, e.g.

```
<div data-react-class="ButtonSwitchToTab" data-react-props="{...}">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ... data-reactid=".2">
    Add / Invite People
  </a>
</div>
```

What I really need is to insert style information into this wrapping div so that components align appropriately, like so:

```
<div data-react-class="ButtonSwitchToTab" data-react-props="{...}"
 style="display:inline-block">  <<<<<------
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ... data-reactid=".2">
    Add / Invite People
  </a>
</div>
```

What's the appropriate way to do that?

Answer (score 11):

Ah, dove deeper into `react_rails` doco ([Helper's signature](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails#rendering--mounting)) and found that I could add pass-through `html_options`.

So:

```
<%= react_component('ButtonSwitchToTab', {prop: .., prop: ..}, 
                    {:style => "display:inline-block"}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to style the component mount point as well, and I just assigned a custom ID to my component:

```
= react_component 'LoginPage', id: 'login-page-container'
```

(HAML template)